# Could not connect to Microsoft Exchange after a few sends

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm sending mails using spring Java mail and Microsoft Exchange.

When I send a single mail all works properly but when I send a few mails closely spaced(just 4 or 5) the server returns a "Connection Timeout". If a retry and retry finally all mails are sent. I've talk to Microsoft support and they said that 30 mails /minute are allowed but I'm not able to send more than 3 or 4. Any idea?

This is my config:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mailHost}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mailPort}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mailUser}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mailPassword}" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

mailHost=smtp.office365.com
mailPort=25
mailUser=xxx
mailPassword=xxx
```

The code that sends the mail:

```
private void sendMail(String subject, String body, boolean isHtml,int atttemp, Attachment attachment, String... to ) {
    log.info("Sending mail("+subject+" to:"+Arrays.toString(to));
    try{
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setFrom(from);
        helper.setText(body, isHtml);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        if (attachment != null){
            log.debug("Adding attachment:"+attachment.getName());
            helper.addAttachment(attachment.getName(),  new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(attachment.getAttachment())));
        }
        mailSender.send(message);
        log.info("Mail sent");
    }catch(MessagingException|MailSendException|MailAuthenticationException e){ 
        log.error("Message:"+e.getMessage());
        if (atttemp < 5){
            log.error("Timeout Exception?. Retrying mail to...: "+Arrays.toString(to)+"; attempt:"+atttemp);
            sendMail(subject, body,isHtml,atttemp++, attachment, to);
        }else{
            log.error("Mail not sent to:"+Arrays.toString(to)+" after "+atttemp+" attemps");
        }

    }catch(Throwable t){
        log.error("Error sending message to:"+Arrays.toString(to)+". ",t);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception I'm getting:

```
2016-04-17 16:39:04,380 ERROR c.h.n.m.MailSender [Thread-2] Message:Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Could you try changing the port to 587?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, i have tried your code. I sent messages from an exchange server (1 at first, then 10 at a time) to both a gmail and a yahoo account. Everything run smoothly. It seems to be more likely something within your environment - and not the code - that seems to be causing issues.

1. I suggest you try different ports: 25, 465, 587
2. Try sending from a gmail account using smtp.gmail.com as server (See: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)
3. Connect to a different ISP if you can
4. Reduce the size of your attachment
5. I have some code below you may use in place of your existing bean.

Sample properties file i.e. messagesender.properties:

```
report.email.from=aaa@gmail.com.com
report.email.to=bbb@gmail.com,ccc@gmail.com
report.email.cc=ddd@gmail.com,eee@gmail.com
report.email.bcc=fff@gmail.com,ggg@gmail.com
report.email.reply.to=hhh@gmail.com
report.email.server=smtp.gmail.com
report.email.port=
report.email.username=
report.email.password=
#SSL,TLS
report.email.encryption.strategy=SSL
report.email.enable.authentication=false
report.email.enable.encryption=false
report.email.subject=Test
report.email.text=This better work!
report.email.retry.interval=15
report.email.fail.attempts=40
```

The code to replace your bean implementation below. This will directly read properties from your properties file placed in your classpath:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("MessageSender")
public class MessageSender2 implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageSender2.class);
    Properties props;
    boolean wait = false;
    Integer retryInterval = 0;
    Integer failAttempts = 0;
    Integer failCount = 0;

    public void composeAndSendMessage(EmailObject reportObjects) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/messagesender.properties"));

        retryInterval = Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty("report.email.retry.interval"));
        failAttempts = Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty("report.email.fail.attempts"));

        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = prepareAttachmentContent(reportObjects);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = prepareMessageContent(mimeMultipart);
        sendMail(mimeMessage);
    }

    private MimeMultipart prepareAttachmentContent(EmailObject reportObject) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        String fileName = reportObject.getFile();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(reportObject.getContent());

        DataSource bads = null;
        bads = new ByteArrayDataSource(bais, "application/pdf");

        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bads));
        bodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        bodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);

        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
        return mimeMultipart;
    }

    private MimeMessage prepareMessageContent(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws MessagingException {

        String fromAdd = props.getProperty("report.email.from");
        String[] recipientCc = null;
        String[] recipientBcc = null;
        String[] recipient = props.getProperty("report.email.to").split(",");
        try {
            recipientCc = props.getProperty("report.email.cc").split(",");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            recipientBcc = props.getProperty("report.email.bcc").split(",");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        String replyTo = props.getProperty("report.email.reply.to");
        String host = props.getProperty("report.email.server");
        String port = props.getProperty("report.email.port");
        String username = props.getProperty("report.email.username");
        String password = props.getProperty("report.email.password");
        String encryptionStrategy = props.getProperty("report.email.encryption.strategy");
        Boolean authenticate = Boolean.valueOf(props.getProperty("report.email.enable.authentication"));
        Boolean encrypt = Boolean.valueOf(props.getProperty("report.email.enable.encryption"));
        String subject = props.getProperty("report.email.subject");
        String text = props.getProperty("report.email.text");

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.from", fromAdd);
        if (port != null && !port.isEmpty()) {
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        }

        if (encrypt != null && encrypt) {
            if (encryptionStrategy != null && encryptionStrategy.equalsIgnoreCase("TLS")) {
                properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            }
            if (encryptionStrategy != null && encryptionStrategy.equalsIgnoreCase("SSL")) {
                properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
                properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            }
        }

        Session session = null;

        if (authenticate != null && authenticate) {
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
                session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            @Override
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }
                        });
            }
        } else {
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        }

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAdd));

        InternetAddress sendTo[] = new InternetAddress[recipient.length];
        for (int h = 0; h < recipient.length; h++) {
            sendTo[h] = new InternetAddress(recipient[h]);
        }
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, sendTo);

        InternetAddress sendToCc[] = null;
        try {
            sendToCc = new InternetAddress[recipientCc.length];
            for (int h = 0; h < recipientCc.length; h++) {
                sendToCc[h] = new InternetAddress(recipientCc[h]);
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, sendToCc);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        InternetAddress sendToBcc[] = null;
        try {
            sendToBcc = new InternetAddress[recipientBcc.length];
            for (int h = 0; h < recipientBcc.length; h++) {
                sendToBcc[h] = new InternetAddress(recipientBcc[h]);
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, sendToBcc);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        InternetAddress[] reply = new InternetAddress[1];
        reply[0] = new InternetAddress(replyTo);

        message.setReplyTo(reply);
        message.setSubject(subject);

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(text);
        messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");

        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(mimeMultipart);
        return message;
    }

    public void sendMail(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {

        failCount++;

        if (failCount > 1) {
            logger.info("Retry email sending . Attempt number : " + (failCount - 1));
        }

        if (failCount < (failAttempts + 1)) {

            if (wait) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(retryInterval * 60000); //Wait 1 minute
                    wait = false;
                    sendMail(message);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                }
            }

            if (!wait) {
                try {
                    Transport.send(message);
                    failCount = 0;
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    logger.error("An exception was thrown during sending email: \n" + exception);
                    wait = true;
                    sendMail(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class EmailObject {
        private byte[] content;
        private String file;

        public EmailObject(byte[] content, String file) {
            this.content = content;
            this.file = file;
        }
        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(byte[] content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
        public String getFile() {
            return file;
        }
        public void setFile(String file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
    }
}
```

You can try the above and see if it helps in any way.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As @JonathanAmos suggested, the problem was not in the code, was in the environment. Amazon ec2 limits the connections to mail ports in order to prevent spam. I request this limitation removal [here](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) and now works fine.